# Handling parameters in method name with equals

Tags: ruby

My method is:

```
def title=(text, sub_text = 'another piece of text')
  self.title = text + sub_text
end
```

Somewhere else in my code, I do something like:

```
subtext = "enhusiasts"
title = "hello ruby "
```

How can I pass `subtext` to the title setter function so that my title becomes:

```
hello ruby enthusiasts
```

Do I have to write a separate function to use this setter?

Answer (score 1):

While there is nothing particularly special about writer methods ending in `=`, the syntax of the language will not allow them to be called with multiple arguments. You can use `send`:

```
object.send :title=, title, subtext
```

That is not a clean solution, though. Also, your `title=` method is recursive; you should be setting an instance variable directly.

I recommend something like this:

```
attr_writer :text, :sub_text

def title
  text + sub_text
end

# ...

object.text = 'hello ruby '
object.sub_text = 'enthusiasts'

object.title
# => "hello ruby enthusiasts"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call it using `self.send('title=', 'string1')` or `self.send('title=', 'string1', 'string2')`.

But you cannot just call it the usual way `title = 'string1', 'string2'`. That is because the parser wont allow it. When `=` is present, the statement is expected to be in `identifier = expression` format.

Better you don"t you name your function with the `=` in such case.

Also it is recommended and is the convention that you concat your string by interpolation i.e.:
`self.title = "#{text} #{sub_text}"` instead of `self.title = text + sub_text`.

This prevents error being generated when text is nil.